# PyQt app does not display when I want to add Toolbar (QObject::disconnected : No such slot ToolBar)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I create an PyQt app and I have an issue when I want to add a toolbar as you can see in files below

***main.py***

```
from window import myAppWindow
from menu import MenuBar
from ToolBar import ToolBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

#Window
windowApp = myAppWindow("pyCompile")
#MenuBar
menuBar = MenuBar()
#ToolBar
toolBar = ToolBar()

windowApp.setMenuBar(menuBar)
windowApp.addToolBar(toolBar)

windowApp.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***menu.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMenuBar

class MenuBar(QMainWindow, QMenuBar):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fileMenu = "&File"
        self.editMenu = "&Edit"
        self.helpMenu = "&Help"
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu(self.editMenu)
        helpMenu = menubar.addMenu(self.helpMenu)
```

***window.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class myAppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, windowTitle):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(150,250,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle(windowTitle)
```

***ToolBar.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QToolBar, QAction


class ToolBar(QMainWindow, QToolBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._createActions()
        self.initUI()
    

    def initUI(self):
        toolBar = self.addToolBar("ToolBar")
        toolBar.setMovable(False)
        toolBar.addAction(self.compileAction)
        toolBar.addAction(self.settingsAction)
        toolBar.addAction(self.quitAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.compileAction = QAction(self)
        self.compileAction.setText("&File")


        self.settingsAction = QAction(self)
        self.settingsAction.setText("&Edit")


        self.quitAction = QAction(self)
        self.quitAction.setText("&Help")
```

When I launch my app I get this message and the window is not display:

> QObject::disconnect: No such slot ToolBar::_q_updateIconSize(QSize)
> QObject::disconnect: No such slot
> ToolBar::_q_updateToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonStyle)

Someone can help me to understand what is appenig ?

Comment: Those inheritances are completely *wrong*. First of all, it doesn't make any sense to inherit from *both* QToolBar/QMenuBar ***and*** QMainWindow, so remove QMainWindow from those class definitions, then remove `self.addToolBar()` and `self.menuBar()` and just use `self.addAction(...)`. Then I strongly urge you to do some research on classes, instances, inheritance, and how they work.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your answer, I am not an expert, I learn POO actually. Thank you I understand my error, and all right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the concepts of inheritance in object-oriented programming.
Anyway, I hope I've helped.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MenuBar(QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fileMenu = "&File"
        self.editMenu = "&Edit"
        self.helpMenu = "&Help"
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = self.addMenu(self.fileMenu)
        editMenu = self.addMenu(self.editMenu)
        helpMenu = self.addMenu(self.helpMenu)


class ToolBar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._createActions()
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        #toolBar = self.addToolBar("ToolBar")
        self.setMovable(False)
        self.addAction(self.compileAction)
        self.addAction(self.settingsAction)
        self.addAction(self.quitAction)

    def _createActions(self):
        self.compileAction = QAction(self)
        self.compileAction.setText("&File")
        self.settingsAction = QAction(self)
        self.settingsAction.setText("&Edit")
        self.quitAction = QAction(self)
        self.quitAction.setText("&Help")


class myAppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, windowTitle):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(150,250,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle(windowTitle)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
windowApp = myAppWindow("pyCompile")
menuBar = MenuBar()
toolBar = ToolBar()
windowApp.setMenuBar(menuBar)
windowApp.addToolBar(toolBar)
windowApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```